# Web Api - IEnumerable with complex type as param is null

Tags: c#, http-post, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api method that looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("message")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(IEnumerable<Email> email)        
    {
        return Ok("message sent");
    }
```

Using Fiddler, I'm sending a request that looks like this:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:3994
Content-Length: 205
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
"To": "someone@emailaddress.com",
"From": "Tom",
"Body": "Cruise",
"Template":"template"
}
```

My Email class looks like this:

```
    public class Email
{
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Template { get; set; }
```

It's hitting my API method, but it's returning null.  I've been googling and trying all different variations of the json request, like:

```
{
    "email": 
        {
            "To": "someone@emailaddress",
            "From": "Tom",
            "Body": "Cruise",
            "Template": "template"
        }        
 }
```

and many other ways, but each time the email param is coming in as null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are posting a single object, but the method expects a collection of objects. Can you please try email: [ { "To": "som............... } ] ?

Comment: try posting `[{
"To": "someone@emailaddress.com",
"From": "Tom",
"Body": "Cruise",
"Template":"template"
}]` as data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want send to only one mail your host method param and json data are wrong

Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("message")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Email email)        
{
    return Ok("message sent");
}
```

Json Data

```
{
"Body":"body",
"From":"from",
"To":"to",
"Template":"template"
}
```

Or  If you want to send more email only your json data is wrong

Json data for more email

```
[
    {"Body":"body","From":"from","To":"to","Template":"template"},
    {"Body":"body1","From":"from1","To":"to1","Template":"template1"},
    {"Body":"body2","From":"from2","To":"to2","Template":"template2"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

From your request, it looks like you only post a single `Email` object, so change your method to:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("message")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Email email)        
{
    return Ok("message sent");
}
```

Also, you may need to wrap your email you are POSTing like:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:3994
Content-Length: 205
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{  
   "email":{  
      "To":"someone@emailaddress.com",
      "From":"Tom",
      "Body":"Cruise",
      "Template":"template"
   }
}
```